# Is there any way to save a patch/diff file in Araxis Merge?

Tags: diff, patch, araxis

I'm merging some code and would like to save one diff to compare against another diff. (I'm in the dreaded diff-the-diff's scenario). Anyhow, the normal way I would do this would be to save to patch files and compare them to make sure the correct changes were applied.

Is there any way to get Araxis to generate a patch file for a diff I'm currently viewing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those little pranksters at Araxis removed the *File* menu. Took me a few minutes to figure out that the *Report* button was now hidden in plain sight, in the middle of the top panel.

For the next wondering soul, a little hint:

[image: The not-so-hidden report button placement]

This gets you to the *Reports* dialog with its nice *UNIX Diff* option.

Answer (score 4):

Well I think I found it. You have to go through the File menu:

```
File -> Report
```

In that dialog there is an option to get a unix diff... viola!